# Could not grab application authorization token

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have big problems with an old Facebook app. I think it uses old oAuth and there the problems begin... It says that appid or appsecret is invalid but it is correct...

Here is all admin.php: [admin.php](http://pastebin.com/5TjAinpP)

Sorry for PasteBin but file is too large to paste it there...

It says: "It appears the application ID and secret key you entered are invalid (Could not grab app authroization token)"

Here is problematic code: [CLICK!](http://pastebin.com/KGXpdY8T)

Can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Looking at your `admin.php`, PHEWWWWW...you know MVC could make your life easier! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the app access token from here for each of your apps
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

it doesnt change unless you reset your secret, you can hardcode it in as a config variable to use as needed.  only really need to get it one time.

Comment: Yeah, but I got multiple apps needed to setup with this... So there will be problem... I insert appid and appsecret into my browser and it generate tokens... I really have no idea how to make it functional... When i use file_get_contents it shows NULL which means function is disabled by server but it isn't...